# Pyspark: Combining multiple columns into one column with json structure in a window of 5 min

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, azure-databricks

I'm working with a PySpark DataFrame containing four columns: `time`, `system`, `Alarm1` and `Alarm2`. It records alarms data for various systems every 30 seconds - 4 minutes.

```
data = [
    ("2022-12-25T20:41:11.125+0000", "sys1", "A", "C" ),
    ("2022-12-25T20:44:27.125+0000", "sys1", "B", "C" ),
    ("2022-12-25T20:47:12.125+0000", "sys1", "A", "B" ),
    ("2022-12-25T20:50:34.125+0000", "sys1", "B", "D" ),
    ("2022-12-25T20:53:42.125+0000", "sys1", "E", "D" ),
    ("2022-12-25T01:25:52.125+0000", "sys2", "A", "F" ),
    ("2022-12-25T01:27:02.125+0000", "sys2", "P", "X" ),
    ("2022-12-25T01:29:34.125+0000", "sys2", "Y", "M" ), 
    ("2022-12-25T01:30:11.125+0000", "sys2", "K", "G" )
]
```

I need code to group the data by system and aggregate it into 5 min intervals. For each interval, I want to capture the start and end times as separate columns.

Aggregation Requirements:

I'd like to add a new column named `Alarms`. Value for this new `Alarms` column is derived by combining all alarm columns `(Alarm1-2)` in the form of json structure `{'<alarm value>': <duration  in seconds>}` where duration in seconds is the sum of differences between consecutive timestamps spent with value alarm-value in any alarm column. Assume that Alarm1 and Alarm2 cannot have the same value at the same timestamp.

```
| time                           | system | Alarm1 | Alarm2 | time_diff |
| ------------------------------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | --------- |
| 2022-12-25T20:41:11.125+0000   | sys1   | A      | C      | 0         |
| 2022-12-25T20:44:27.125+0000   | sys1   | B      | C      | 196       |
| 2022-12-25T20:47:12.125+0000   | sys1   | A      | B      | 165       |
| 2022-12-25T20:50:34.125+0000   | sys1   | B      | D      | 202       |
| 2022-12-25T20:53:42.125+0000   | sys1   | E      | D      | 188       |
| 2022-12-25T01:25:52.125+0000   | sys2   | A      | F      | 0         |
| 2022-12-25T01:27:02.125+0000   | sys2   | P      | X      | 70        |
| 2022-12-25T01:29:34.125+0000   | sys2   | Y      | M      | 152       |
| 2022-12-25T01:30:11.125+0000   | sys2   | K      | G      | 37        |
```

So, the output that I'm expecting is given below:

| start time | end time | system | Alarms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-25T20:40:00.125+0000 | 2022-12-25T20:45:00.125+0000 | sys1 | {"A":0 , "B": 0, "C":196 } |
| 2022-12-25T20:45:00.125+0000 | 2022-12-25T20:50:00.125+0000 | sys1 | {"A": 165, "B": 165 } |
| 2022-12-25T20:50:00.125+0000 | 2022-12-25T20:55:00.125+0000 | sys1 | {"B": 202, "D": 390, "E": 188 } |
| 2022-12-25T01:25:00.125+0000 | 2022-12-25T01:30:00.125+0000 | sys2 | {"A": 0, "F": 0, "M": 152, "P": 70, "X": 70, "Y": 152} |
| 2022-12-25T20:30:00.125+0000 | 2022-12-25T20:35:00.125+0000 | sys2 | {"K": 37, "G": 37} |

I tried doing `pivots` on `Alarm1` and `Alarm2` `grouby system` separately and performing a `join` operation on both dataframes based on `window` but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm looking for a generic solution which can work even in case I have upto 10 `Alarm` columns : `Alarm1-10`

Comment: Are you using azure databricks or AWS?

Comment: Azure databricks